# Postgres SQL query not using indices defined on columns in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having difficulty with querying a legacy table in an app I'm working on.  There's a query that hits a table with around 15 million rows in it that is consistently taking around 15 seconds to complete, but I feel like it should be a lot faster than that.  The table looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo_files (
  id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  deleted boolean NOT NULL,
  person_id varchar,
  parent_id varchar
);
```

There are also indices defined on the `deleted`, `person_id`, and `parent_id` columns:

```sql
CREATE INDEX index_foo_files_on_parent_id ON foo_files(parent_id);
CREATE INDEX index_foo_files_on_person_id ON foo_files(person_id);
CREATE INDEX index_foo_files_on_deleted ON foo_files(deleted);
```

The query I'm running is looking for all files where `deleted` is `false`, `person_id` is `null`, and `parent_id` is a specific value - say, `abc123`

If I run this query with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` enabled, this is what I see:

```
=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM foo_files
  WHERE                                                             
    deleted IS FALSE AND
    person_id IS NULL AND
    parent_id = 'abc123';
                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on foo_files  (cost=10.45..964.90 rows=162 width=62) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=0 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((parent_id)::text = 'abc123'::text)
   Filter: ((deleted IS FALSE) AND (person_id IS NULL))
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_foo_files_on_parent_id  (cost=0.00..10.41 rows=246 width=0) (actual time=0.012..0.013 rows=0 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((parent_id)::text = 'abc123'::text)
 Planning Time: 0.216 ms
 Execution Time: 0.032 ms
(7 rows)
```

So the conditions on the `deleted` and `person_id` columns are taking nearly two orders of magnitude more time than the third column.  I can't figure out why the indices on both the `deleted` column and the `person_id` column aren't being used here (i.e., the bitmap heap scan), whereas the index on the `parent_id` *is* being used (i.e., the index scan).

As an experiment I tried creating a partial index on the `deleted` and `person_id` columns like this:

```
CREATE INDEX index_foo_files_composite ON foo_files(parent_id) WHERE deleted IS FALSE AND person_id IS NULL;
```

and that sped the query up *some*

```
                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                             
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on foo_files  (cost=5.81..634.55 rows=161 width=62) (actual time=0.031..0.032 rows=0 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (((parent_id)::text = 'abc123'::text) AND (deleted IS FALSE) AND (person_id IS NULL))
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_foo_files_composite  (cost=0.00..5.77 rows=161 width=0) (actual time=0.030..0.030 rows=0 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((parent_id)::text = 'abc123'::text)
 Planning Time: 0.178 ms
 Execution Time: 0.045 ms
(6 rows)
```

Am I missing something?  This *feels* like it should perform a lot faster.  How can I modify the indices to be more performant, or modify the query to use the available indices?

Comment: `Execution Time: 0.032 ms`, that's not even close to 15 milliseconds. Why do you think this query takes 15 seconds?

Comment: The parent index is probably the best choice, because there will be many more rows that are undeleted for instance. If you want an index that is even more appropriate for your query, then create a compostite index:  `create index idx on foo_files (parent_id, deleted, person_id)` or just a covering index on the parent_id: `create index idx on foo_files (parent_id) include (deleted, person_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your performance is great. I think you're misreading the explain results. Your first query executes in 0.032 ms, which is nothing. Your second query with the composite index is *slower* at 0.045 ms. See [Using EXPLAIN - EXPLAIN ANALYZE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-ANALYZE) in the PostgreSQL docs.

---

*Generally*, only one index will be used per query.

In this case, the query planner has decided that a Bitmap Index Scan `parent_id = 'abc123'` will return very few rows (246) and then it can simply scan those rows with a Bitmap Heap Scan for `deleted IS FALSE AND person_id IS NULL`.

It has determined this will be faster than retrieving all the `deleted IS FALSE` rows from the deleted index (every undeleted row in your table, likely many rows), and also retrieving all the rows where `person_id is NULL` from the person_id index (depends on your data, could be many, could be very few), and also retrieving all the rows where `parent_id = 'abc123'` from the parent_id index (few rows) and then taking the intersection of all three.

And, as can be seen from the explain, your query is executing in 0.032ms. That is very fast.

You can read more about Bitmap Heap Scan [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/12553.1135634231@sss.pgh.pa.us) and

---

Since most queries are likely to also query for `deleted is FALSE` you can try a composite index which includes `deleted` such as `(parent_id, deleted)` or `(person_id, deleted)`. The utility of such an index depends on the percentage of deleted rows.

With three values there are 7 query combinations.

- parent_id
- person_id
- deleted
- parent_id + person_id
- parent_id + deleted
- person_id + deleted
- parent_id + person_id + deleted

Composite B-Tree indexes can cover searches and order by for their first key, as well as searches and order by their first and second key. While it's possible to also cover searches for only their second key, it is not efficient.

You can cover all possibilities with these three indexes.

```
-- For searches on parent_id, parent_id + person_id, parent_id + person_id + deleted
(parent_id, person_id, deleted)
-- For searches on person_id, person_id + deleted
(person_id, deleted)
-- For searches on deleted, parent_id + deleted
(deleted, parent_id)
```

However, this is not necessarily the most efficient way to index. Composite indexes can be slower than non-composite indexes. Right now your performance is great.

---

An alternative approach would be to partition the table on `deleted`. That would greatly simplify indexing: just `(parent_id, person_id)` and `(person_id)` would cover all possible queries. It would also avoid locking the table while dropping deleted rows.

As a final optimization, you can replace the `deleted` flag with a `deleted_at` timestamp. Then you can partition on `deleted_at` by time period (probably by month or year, depends on how fast your deleted rows grow). This lets you very efficiently drop old rows by simply deleting old partitions. This avoids the problem of your table growing indefinitely.

Another alternative approach is rather than storing deleted rows within the main table, use an "audit" table to store changed and deleted rows. See [paper_trail](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail) for one example of how this might work. This is usually best when you only rarely want to query deleted rows.